# Ant: How to copy file from classpath

Tags: ant

I have file.txt in some jar. Ant is executed with this jar on classpath. This

```
<available resource="file.txt" property="file.txt.exists"/>
```

sets the property.

How can I copy that resource to some location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming for you have two files in a directory:

- build.xml
- test.jar

---

build.xml

```
<project name="copy-file-from-jar-on-ant-classpath" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">
        <copy tofile="extracted.file.txt">
            <javaresource name="file.txt"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

---

test.jar contains a single file: file.txt

---

Running the following command...

> ant -lib test.jar

...will extract file.txt from test.jar into the directory.